# Import Excel Data into R

Tags: r, excel, algorithm, matrix

I'm working on an excel-file consisting of a 261 x 10 matrix. The matrix consists of the weekly returns of 10 stocks from 2010 to 2015. So, I have 10 variables (stocks) and 261 observations (weekly returns) for each variable.
For my master thesis I have to apply a "rearrangement algorithm" developed by Rüschendorf and Puccetti (2012) on my matrix. I'm not going into further details on the theorical side of that concept. The thing is that I downloaded a package capable of performing the rearrangement algorithm in R. I tested it out and it works perfectly.

Actually the only thing I need to know is how to import my excel-matrix into R in order to be capable of performing the rearrangement algorithm on it. I can rewrite my matrix into R (manually) just by encoding every element of the matrix by using the matrix programming formula in R:

```
A = matrix( c(), nrow= , ncol= , byrow=TRUE)
```

The problem is that doing so for such a big matrix (261 x 10) would be very time consuming. Is their any way to import my excel-matrix in R and that R recognizes it as matrix consisting of numerical values ready for calculations (similar to the case of doing it manually) ? In such a way that I just have to run the "rearrangement algorithm" function provided in R.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are a number of ways of doing this. Probably the easiest would be to save the Excel file as a CSV, then call `read.csv()` in R, and finally coerce to matrix via `as.matrix()`.

Comment: So the question is about how to import data.

Answer (score 1):

I make a selection within an opened Excel sheet and copied to the clipboard. This then worked on a Mac:

```
> con=pipe("pbpaste")
> dat <- data.matrix( read.table(con) )
> dat
      V1 V2 V3
 [1,]  1  1  1
 [2,]  2  2  2
 [3,]  3  3  3
 [4,]  4  4  4
 [5,]  5  5  5
 [6,]  6  6  6
 [7,]  7  7  7
 [8,]  8  8  8
 [9,]  9  9  9
[10,] 10 10 10
[11,] 11 11 11
[12,] 12 12 12
[13,] 13 13 13
[14,] 14 14 14
```

The method is somewhat different on Windows devices but the help page for `?connections` should have your OS-specific techniques.

Comment: +1 I really like this idea; going through the clipboard is probably the quickest solution possible. And you can collapse the two lines into one by using `system2()`. For example, this works for me on Cygwin (although I should point out that the Cygwin `getclip` utility doesn't handle UTF-8 characters correctly): `as.matrix(read.table(text=system2('getclip',stdout=T)))`.

Comment: @bgoldst, why not just do `as.matrix(read.table('clipboard'))`?

Comment: @r2evans Very nice, I didn't know about that feature! Unfortunately, from my testing on `x86_64-unknown-cygwin`, it only seems to work when I first create an X11 window from the R session. It also seems to work in RStudio on Windows, but I can't comment on other platforms.

Comment: I've always used `x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64` which could be causing the difference, but this is a mainstay for me for quick toggling between spreadsheet work and *R* work (a good pair at times).

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide a minimal reproducible example, so the answers are probably gonna of lesser quality. Anyway, you should be able to load the the excel file with something like:

```
require(XLConnect)
wrkbk <- loadWorkbook("path/to/your/data.xlsx")
df <- readWorksheet(wrkbk, sheet = 1, header = TRUE)
```

And then convert the `data.frame` to a `matrix` via

```
ans <- as.matrix(df)
```

Otherwise, you need to save your file as a `.txt` or `.csv` plain-text file and use `read.table` or `read.csv` and the like. Consult their respective help pages.